# How to cast dynamically to generic type

Tags: java, generics, javafx, annotations

I have the following 2 classes BaseObject:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public static Predicate<? extends BaseObject> isNameEqualTo(String test) 
    {
         return p -> p.getName().equals(test);
    }
}
```

and User:

```
public class User extends BaseObject
{
     private String firstName;

     public static Predicate<? extends User> isFirstNameEqualTo(String test) 
     {
          return p -> p.getFirstName().equals(test);
     }
}
```

What I would like to do achieve is a way for the user to open a dialog and filter data in a table. The table consists of an `ObservableList<? extends BaseObject>` backed by a `FilteredList`. So when the user opens the dialog, there should be list, table,...with all filterable fields like firstname, lastname, etc. Every class that extends `BaseObject` should provide static methods that return a `Predicate` like the following

```
@FilterableField(name="firstName")
public static Predicate<? extends User> isFirstNameEqualTo(String test) 
{
    return p -> p.getFirstName().equals(test);
}
```

The annotation `@FilterableField` is meant as an indicator if a field is filterable and as a container of metainformation about the field itself. Now my problem is that using reflection I cannot cast a `Predicate` to `Predicate<? extends User>` using the following piece of (test!) code:

```
Set<Method> allMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(User.class);
    Map<FilterableField, Method> annotatedMethods = new HashMap<>();
    for(Method m : allMethods)
    {
        FilterableField annotation = m.getAnnotation(FilterableField.class);
        if(annotation == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
    annotatedMethods.put(annotation, m);
}
annotatedMethods.forEach((k,v)->{
    System.out.println("Annotation : " + k.name() + " Method : " + v.getName());
if(k.name().equals("name"))
        {
            try
            {
                //Class clz = v.getDeclaringClass();
                Class clz = Class.forName("Predicate<User>");
                Predicate test = (Predicate<?>)v.invoke(null, "Hans");
                clz.cast(test);
                List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
                User user = new User();
                user.setName("Hans");
                users.add(user);
                user = new User();
                user.setName("Werner");
                users.add(user);
                List<User> dummy = users.stream().filter(test).collect(Collectors.toList());
                System.out.println("Main.reflectionPredicateTest - dummy: "+dummy);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

So if anyone has some ideas on how to achieve this and/or how to cast a class instance dynamically to something like `Predicate<? extends User>`, I'd be more than thankful!

Comment: A few notes: 1) due to type erasure there is no class called `Predicate<User>`, there's only `Predicate`. 2) you are not using the return value of `clz.cast(test);` so that call doesn't do anything except throw exceptions if you can't cast.

Comment: `Predicate<? extends User>` makes no sense, since that generic type is strictly a consumer. You'd want `Predicate<? super User>`.

Comment: What do you mean by cast dynamically? Do yo know the class name ("Predicate<User>" in your example) at compilation time or only at runtime?

Comment: I just tried using `Predicate` instead of `Predicate<User>` to filter my test list and it worked like a charm. Thanks! Don't know why I hadn't thought of giving that a try sooner...